# Error while using laravel 5.4 session

Tags: php, laravel, session

I am new to laravel session:

here is my code to get session:

```
Session::set('user_id', $user);
$session_id = Session::get('user_id');
echo $session_id;exit;
```

Included namespaces:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;use App\Role;use App\User;use DB;
```

Error is:

> FatalThrowableError in Manager.php line 137:
>   Call to undefined method Illuminate\Session\Store::set()

Thanks to all for any help.

Answer (score 3):

In laravel 5.4 `Session::set` changed to `Session::put` try

```
Session::put('user_id', 'user_id');
$session_id = Session::get('user_id');
dd($session_id);exit;
```

You'll get your session result;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the solution already provided. With Laravel 5.4, you have access to global helpers so you don't have to always import classes to your controller. For sessions, you could do

```
session(['user_id' => 'user_id']); //or
session()->put('user_id', 'user_id');

//You retrieve like this
$session_id = session('user_id');
```